# Combinatorial Optimisation(?) - Maximising Effective Delivery

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

I have a problem and am terrible at math, but I know it can be solved with math.

To explain the problem I will reduce it to something simple.

I have **containers** that can only take certain items, so let's say X-type containers can only take on X.

I have **packages** that contain a combination of things, let's call the things X, Y, Z.

The **containers can only be used once**, and the **packages must be delivered together**. Each package contains different combinations of things; for example, one package contains X,X,X and another contains X,X,Y.

Now, what I need to understand is what type of math/equations/functions etc. help me determine the best packages I should take on to maximise the utility of my containers. Note, I CANNOT separate the packages.

An additional complexity is stated for consideration:

1. Certain packages are better delivered together; is there a way of determining which ones work best together?

Comment: I assume that your packages hold containers ? or is it the reverse ?

Comment: I don't think this is clear.  You have "things", "containers", and "packages".  I gather that things can go in containers...can packages also go in containers?  Can we unpack the packages and distribute the things they contain?  If so, how would that work with respect to the constraint on containers?

Comment: The generic math problem (which is not easy to solve except for small examples) is "constrained bin packing", I believe.